# Component not re-rendering after Context change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

"myGroups" is a context variable. In my context store, I am fetching data from a database and populating this "myGroups" variable. So initially it contains only an empty array, after some time it contains an array of objects. e.g. [{id: "", data: ""}]

I want to render these groups. So I am mapping through the myGroups variable, and trying to render them.

But the problem is that even after context updating, my component does not re-render. I have console logged and seen that the fetching of data works absolutely fine, though it takes some time to do so.

Does changing the context does not rerender it's consumer? Why is the component not rerendering? It would be of great help if you can provide some solution. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import "../css/MyGroups.css";
import GroupCard from './GroupCard';
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState';

const MyGroups = () => {
    const { myGroups } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    useEffect(() => console.log(myGroups), [myGroups]); // Debugging 

    return (
        <div className="my__groups">
            <h1 className="my__groups__heading">My Groups</h1>
            <div className="my__groups__underline"></div>
            <div className="my__groups__grid__container">
                {
                    myGroups.map(({id, data}) => (
                        <GroupCard
                            key={id}
                            name={data.name}
                            image={data.image} 
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyGroups
```

This is what I get on the console when the context changes:
[Console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e700.png)

My Global Provider:

```
<GlobalProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Main />
      </BrowserRouter>
</GlobalProvider>
```

The MyGroups Component is a descendant of the Main Component.

**Edit 1: Fetch Function of my Store**

```
function fetchGroupsFromDatabase(id) {
        let myGroups = [];
        db.collection("users").doc(id).get() // Fetch user details with given id 
            .then(doc => {
                doc.data().groupIDs.map(groupID => { // Fetch all group IDs of the user
                    db.collection("groups").doc(groupID).get() // Fetch all the groups 
                        .then(doc => {
                            myGroups.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()})
                        })
                })
            })
            .then(() => {
                const action = {
                    type: FETCH_GROUPS_FROM_DATABASE,
                    payload: myGroups
                };
                dispatch(action);
            })
    }
```

**Edit 2: Reducer**

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_GROUPS_FROM_DATABASE:
            return {
                ...state, 
                myGroups: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default Reducer;
```

Comment: You really don't need to save `myGroups` inside the local state of your component. Whenever something in the Context gets updated, all the components, that consume that context, are re-rendered. So, using `useState` to save some data from the Context is completely unnecessary.

Comment: can you share your `GlobalContext`?

Answer (score 1):

As [Yousaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6094348/yousaf) said, not need to using `useState` and `useEffect`. You can use context in two different way

**first**:

```
const MyGroups = () => (
  <GlobalContext.Consumer>
    {({ myGroups }) => (
         <div className="my__groups">
            <h1 className="my__groups__heading">My Groups</h1>
            <div className="my__groups__underline"></div>
            <div className="my__groups__grid__container">
                {myGroups.map(({id, data}) => (
                        <GroupCard
                            key={id}
                            name={data.name}
                            image={data.image} 
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )}
  </GlobalContext.Consumer>
);
```

**second**:

```
const MyGroups = () => {
  const { myGroups } = useContext(GlobalContext);

  return (
    <div className="my__groups">
      <h1 className="my__groups__heading">My Groups</h1>
      <div className="my__groups__underline"></div>
      <div className="my__groups__grid__container">
        {myGroups.map(({ id, data }) => (
          <GroupCard key={id} name={data.name} image={data.image} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Edit**:
the problem comes from the Fetch Function it based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65763516/12608714) should be like this:

```
async function fetchGroupsFromDatabase(id) {
    const doc = await db.collection("users").doc(id).get() // Fetch user details with given id 
    const myGroups = await Promise.all(
        doc.data().groupIDs.map(groupID => // Fetch all group IDs of the user
            db.collection("groups").doc(groupID).get() // Fetch all the groups 
                .then(doc => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }))
        )
    );
    const action = {
        type: FETCH_GROUPS_FROM_DATABASE,
        payload: myGroups
    };
    dispatch(action);
}
```

Comment: Followed your syntax...but my component is not re-rendering either on context change or state change...

Comment: can you share your GlobalContext? Did you wrap your component inside `GlobalContext`?

Comment: <GlobalProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Main />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </GlobalProvider>

Comment: The MyGroups component is a descendant component of the Main component.

Comment: I have also shown image of console logs of myGroups context at the last of my question. You can also have a look and inspect that.

Comment: Can you make codesandbox from your components? ill help you on that.

Comment: I think problem is not with the component, the problem is in my store. Because when I am setting up a dummy fetch with setTimeout, the component is working absolutely fine....

Comment: So I am pasting the code of the function which is fetching the data from the database, and maybe then u can find some fault....even if u can't, then I will make a sandbox....pls check the edit

Comment: this is fine, please share the reducer aswell.

Comment: Check out a more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65763473/13128845

Comment: Yes problem is solved....thank you for your concern

Comment: Nice job, no problem.

Comment: I did edit my answer based on your other question for the future.