# Can an action be dispatched inside the THEN construct of a promise?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-context

The following is a component that maps through the objects in a context variable and renders them.

```
const MyGroups = () => {
    const { myGroups } = useContext(GlobalContext);

    return (
        <div className="my__groups">
            <h1 className="my__groups__heading">My Groups</h1>
            <div className="my__groups__underline"></div>
            <div className="my__groups__grid__container">
                {
                    myGroups.map(({id, data}) => (
                        <GroupCard
                            key={id}
                            name={data.name}
                            image={data.image} 
                        />
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The following is my store function which I use to fetch my data from Firebase and dispatch an action to the Reducer.

```
function fetchGroupsFromDatabase(id) {
        let myGroups = [];
        db.collection("users").doc(id).get() // Fetch user details with given id 
            .then(doc => {
                doc.data().groupIDs.map(groupID => { // Fetch all group IDs of the user
                    db.collection("groups").doc(groupID).get() // Fetch all the groups 
                        .then(doc => {
                            myGroups.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()})
                        })
                })
            })
            .then(() => {
                const action = {
                    type: FETCH_GROUPS_FROM_DATABASE,
                    payload: myGroups
                };
                dispatch(action);
            })
    }
```

Now, the problem is that the "GroupCards" that I want to render, are not rendering although I can see in the console that the context variable get's populated after some time.

**Working perfectly with setTimeout()**

However, I have observed that instead of dispatching the action within the THEN construct, if I dispatch my action after some seconds by setTimeout, my component renders perfectly, like this:

```
function fetchGroupsFromDatabase(id) {
        let myGroups = [];
        db.collection("users").doc(id).get() // Fetch user details with given id 
            .then(doc => {
                doc.data().groupIDs.map(groupID => { // Fetch all group IDs of the user
                    db.collection("groups").doc(groupID).get() // Fetch all the groups 
                        .then(doc => {
                            myGroups.push({id: doc.id, data: doc.data()})
                        })
                })
            })

            setTimeout(() => {
                const action = {
                    type: FETCH_GROUPS_FROM_DATABASE,
                    payload: myGroups
                };
                dispatch(action);
            }, 3000);
    }
```

I humbly request you to kindly spare some of your valuable time and provide some solution to my problem.

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to wait for all of the groups `.get()` calls to resolve, and to dispatch with the results, use `Promise.all`:

```
async function fetchGroupsFromDatabase(id) {
    const doc = await db.collection("users").doc(id).get() // Fetch user details with given id 
    const myGroups = await Promise.all(
        doc.data().groupIDs.map(groupID => // Fetch all group IDs of the user
            db.collection("groups").doc(groupID).get() // Fetch all the groups 
                .then(doc => ({ id: doc.id, data: doc.data() }))
        )
    );
    const action = {
        type: FETCH_GROUPS_FROM_DATABASE,
        payload: myGroups
    };
    dispatch(action);
}
```

Comment: But can u pls explain if I dispatch my action within the THEN, why is it not working?

Comment: You mean the first snippet in your question? It takes time for the `.get` Promise to resolve. So you've made a bunch of async requests inside the first `.then`, but since that first doesn't return anything, the next `.then` runs immediately, before the requests have completed - that's why using `setTimeout` happens to work (but using `Promise.all` is much better).

Comment: Oh okay, so if a then does not return anything, the next then in the chain get's executed immediately?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only if you return a Promise, and that Promise takes some time to resolve, will the next `.then` take some time to run - it'll then wait for that returned Promise to resolve first.